# Property or indexer 'Form.MdiChildren' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Tags: c#, winforms

I keep getting the error in the title, and I can't figure out where the Form is set to read-only or how I can disable this.

```
private void studentToolStripMenuItem1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            addStudent newStudentForm = new addStudent(this);
            newStudentForm.MdiChildren = this;
            newStudentForm.Show();
        }
```

`addStudent` is a form that takes care of creating students, and populating a list of students which is kept on the main form. So I want to be able to edit data on Form1 from Form2 which is why I am using Mdi

Can anyone give me any tips on where I should be looking at what I should be looking for to fix this error?

EDIT: To be clear

```
Form1 = Parent

Form2 = Child
```

Comment: You're just looking at it backwards. Set the parent not the children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MdiChildren` is just an array, which represents the current forms, which are the Mdi Childs of the dialog. You need to load the MDI child into the parent.

Something like this:

```
addStudent newStudentForm = new addStudent();
newStudentForm.MdiParent = this;
newStudentForm.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set `MdiChildren`. Moreover, you wouldn't be able to set it this way even if it wasn't readonly - it is a collection of forms, not a form.

Logically, you try to tell that "newStudentForm has current form as MDI child", and is isn't true, you actually need "newStudentForm is a new MDI child of this".

The only thing you need to do is to set `MdiParent` in your child form:

```
private void studentToolStripMenuItem1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  AddStudent newStudentForm = new AddStudent(this);
  newStudentForm.MdiParent = this;
  newStudentForm.Show();
}
```

P.S. Please, use proper naming for your classes. It shuld be `AddStudent`, not `addStudent`. This one letter makes code absolutely unreadable.